# Removing Extra Height Added By Controls In Video.js

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I'm trying to use video.js to embed video in my website.

I have the script installed and working perfect, well almost!

The problem I'm having is that when you load the page, then play the video, then stop the video, there is a big black line across the top of the video.

This is being added to the top (and bottom) of the container by the control bar - assuming so that the controls don't cut into the video.

However, I don't want this extra height being added. Does anyone know how to stop this being added?